# Silverlight 4 C# - How to catch a NullReferenceException?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, nullreferenceexception

Here's my code:

```
if (dataGrid.CurrentColumn.DisplayIndex == 1)
            txtArticle.Text += " " + ((TextBlock)dataGrid.CurrentColumn.GetCellContent(dataGrid.SelectedItem)).Text + " ";
```

This works beautifully if I've already populated the datagrid with something, but throws a NullReferenceException if it has yet to be filled with anything. I tried an if statement to check for a null value - `if (dataGrid.CurrentColumn.DisplayIndex == null)`, but that had no effect.

How do I handle this?

Thanks,

-Sootah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think @Fredrik meant to type:

```
if (dataGrid.CurrentColumn != null && dataGrid.CurrentColumn.DisplayIndex == 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

I would assume that it is `dataGrid.CurrentColumn` that is null, not `dataGrid.CurrentColumn.DisplayIndex`, so that is what you should check in the if statement:

```
if (dataGrid.CurrentColumn != null && dataGrid.CurrentColumn.DisplayIndex == 1)
    txtArticle.Text += " " + ((TextBlock)dataGrid.CurrentColumn.GetCellContent(dataGrid.SelectedItem)).Text + " ";
```